# Enable text highlighting in swing message-box

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Say i'm using the following code to prompt an error message in my simple swing application:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Is there any way I could make it possible for the user to highlight text sections (for copy/paste purpose)?

Many thanks.

Comment: What "sections" would you like to allow them to be able to highlight? The message? And what is held by the message variable?

Comment: I meant sections of the message string that is held by the message variable

Comment: *"an error message in my simple swing application:"*  If the app. were simple (for the *user*) it would probably not show any part of the error message as produced by the J2SE, and instead have a `Submit Bug Report` button which will either copy/paste the lot of it into an email, or do something more intelligent (e.g. send it directly back to your server).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
 JTextArea textarea= new JTextArea("add your message here");
 textarea.setEditable(true);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textarea, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: That allows user to edit the text and looks stupid because it has white background.

Answer (score 2):

JOptionPane can be constructed with any object, not just a string message.  So you could construct a JTextArea and pass that to the JOptionPane as your message.  That should allow copy paste.

Answer (score 2):

If you object to the white background shown by the default JTextArea, you can set the JTextArea background color equal to the JOptionPane's background color.

```
String title = "foo";
String message = "Select me";

JTextArea msg = new JTextArea(message);
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(msg, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
msg.setBackground(pane.getBackground());
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, title);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```